# Solr edismax query not returning any result

Tags: solr, edismax

the following solr query is eluding me, can anyone provide some advice?

```
fq={!edismax qf=$kwf}myToken&kwf=schemaField1 schemaField2
```

when myToken is found in the first field all is well, but I never get any hit on the second. I have already checked the tokenizer and analyzer configurations and they seem OK.

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory" ... />
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Is there anything else I could be doing obviously wrong?

Best,
Edoardo

Comment: Can you debugQuery and check what the search debug looks like ? Any reason why you are using fq and not q ? Also i would suggest configuring a request handler for the same ?